# Why can't I use iCloud to backup?

Tags: ipad, icloud, backup

I am trying to sync my iPad running iOS 8.0.2 with my iCloud account and it keeps telling me that I need more space. I have deleted everything I can and deselected every single app from the backup but it still says I need 5.1gb of space.

[image: Screen Shot showing 5gb free and 5.1gb needed]

If I try clicking back up I get the following error

[image: iCloud fail error message]

I have only one device, my iPad, linked to iCloud. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you go to "Show all Apps", are there any left which are selected?

Comment: Hi @patrix, no, I have deselected every app in the list.